# How Can I sort and array by values? e.g first 4's than 2's than 16's

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, object, key-value

I tried this as known

```
 test.sort(function (a, b) {
    var textA = a[0].Val1;
    var textB = b[0].Val1;
    if (textA > textB)
        return -1;
    if (textA < textB)
        return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

but I want to see my sorted array like this

```
{name: 'John', Val1: 4, hireDate: "July 1, 2010"},
{name: 'XXX', Val1: 4, hireDate: "August 15, 2009"},
{name: 'YYY', Val1: 2, hireDate: "August 15, 2009"},
{name: 'ZZZ', Val1: 2, hireDate: "August 15, 2009"},
{name: 'ZZZ', Val1: 16, hireDate: "August 15, 2009"},
{name: 'ZZZ', Val1: 16, hireDate: "August 15, 2009"},
{name: 'Ana', Val1: 1, hireDate: "December 12, 2011"}
```

Comment: Is there any particular logic behind such order or it should be just hardcoded?

Comment: I think, It should be `a.Val1` instead of `a[0].Val1`, `a` is a element of array. Similarly for `b`.

Comment: `test.sort((a, b) => a.toString().localeCompare(b))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by creating an ordering object.

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'John', Val1: 4, hireDate: 'July 1, 2010' },
  { name: 'XXX', Val1: 4, hireDate: 'August 15, 2009' },
  { name: 'YYY', Val1: 2, hireDate: 'August 15, 2009' },
  { name: 'ZZZ', Val1: 2, hireDate: 'August 15, 2009' },
  { name: 'ZZZ', Val1: 16, hireDate: 'August 15, 2009' },
  { name: 'ZZZ', Val1: 16, hireDate: 'August 15, 2009' },
  { name: 'Ana', Val1: 1, hireDate: 'December 12, 2011' },
];

const order = { 4: 1, 2: 2, 16: 3 };
data.sort(
  (x, y) =>
    (order[x.Val1] || Number.MAX_VALUE) - (order[y.Val1] || Number.MAX_VALUE)
);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: The OP didn't really word the question very well, he's basically wanting to sort by `Val1` in text ordering descending..

Comment: works very well on console. but it doesn't work in the .js file

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work in `.js file`?

Comment: what is your node version?

Comment: Im using bootstrap v.3 and visual studio 2017

Comment: @kaganbişkiner now check it. I have updated the code.

Comment: @mrhr works fine for me thanks sir have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

You can define the order in a separate `scores` list, and use [`.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) as follows:

```js
const test = [
  {name: 'John', Val1: 4, hireDate: "July 1, 2010"},
  {name: 'XXX', Val1: 4, hireDate: "August 15, 2009"},
  {name: 'YYY', Val1: 2, hireDate: "August 15, 2009"},
  {name: 'ZZZ', Val1: 2, hireDate: "August 15, 2009"},
  {name: 'ZZZ', Val1: 16, hireDate: "August 15, 2009"},
  {name: 'ZZZ', Val1: 16, hireDate: "August 15, 2009"},
  {name: 'Ana', Val1: 1, hireDate: "December 12, 2011"}
];
const scores = [4,2,16];
const MAX = scores.length;

const sorted = test.sort((a, b) => {

  let indexOfA = scores.indexOf(a.Val1);
  indexOfA = (indexOfA >= 0) ? indexOfA : MAX;
  
  let indexOfB = scores.indexOf(b.Val1);
  indexOfB = (indexOfB >= 0) ? indexOfB : MAX;
  
  return indexOfA - indexOfB;
});

console.log(sorted);
```

Comment: The OP didn't really word the question very well, he's basically wanting to sort by `Val1` in text ordering descending..